# Java, Type Substitution

Tags: java, oop

In Java, type substitution is

1. A subclass object can substitute super-class object
2. A super-class object can substitute subclass object
3. A super-class variable can refer subclass object
4. A subclass variable can refer super-class object
   I am confuse with options
   which option is right?

Comment: why my question is mark as negative ?

Comment: What do you *think* the right answer is? Are there any answers that you can rule out? What exactly is confusing you? You're probably getting downvotes because your question doesn't show that you've put any effort into figuring out the problem for yourself.

Comment: i am confuse with option 2 and 4 so i am asking this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do some research on the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  It's an object-oriented fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is option 3.

You can hold object of sub-class in variable or reference of super class!

That is if

`class A extends B`

then

`B b = new A()`

is perfectly fine!